# confusion with pointers and virtual memory in C

Tags: c, operating-system, virtual-memory

i think my question is so simple but i could not find an answer to it.
based on my understanding of virtual memory:

> every process receives a contiguous address space which is mapped to
>   physical memory.

so, code that i write in my program should be able to access any where in virtual memory given to it so i wrote following code in C which throws an exception of type "access violation exception".

i would appreciate if some one explain to me the reason.

here is the code:

```
int* a = 1; // pointer to 1st block of memory
*a = 5; // set the content of pointer to 5, but throws exception
```

Comment: you can't write to memory you don't own. A portion of the address space is reserved (not mapped)

Comment: Who said all of your memory was writable? Also, why do you think it stays contiguous?

Comment: `every process receives a contiguous address space which is mapped to physical memory` This is an OS matter, subject to its memory handling. `following code in C which throws an exception` This is a `C` code matter. The `C` standard doesn't know about the particular OS you may have in mind, and can't address that part. As far as the `C` standard goes, memory that you haven't acquired in some `C` standard way (such as `malloc`, or defining a variable) does not exist for practical purposes, and causes UB (undefined behavior) if accessed.

Comment: Read wikipages about [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory), [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space), [pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_%28computer_programming%29), [pointer aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_aliasing), [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every process receives a contiguous LOGICAL address space. Not a contiguous VIRTUAL address space.

Logical PAGES are mapped to physical PAGE FRAMES.

The logical mapping is done using a PAGE TABLE, containing mappings from local pages to page frames.

However, the page table may not have a mapping to a page frame for every logical page.

There are two reasons why this may happen. First, the operating system may not (an usually does not) create page table entries that span the entire address space. The system parameters or process quotas may limit the size of the logical address space. Some systems also reserve ranges of addresses as being unusable.

Second, someone has to do the mapping of logical pages. This is a two step process. (1) Someone (usually the loader) has to mark logical pages as valid. (2) the operating system has to map the logical page to a physical page. This is done when the process access a valid logical page that does not have a mapping, causing a page fault. (that is virtual memory—the dynamic remapping of a valid logical page to a page frame).

A page table entry can have three states:

1. It is invalid
2. It is valid and maps to a mapping page frame
3. It is valid but has no mapping to a physical page frame. (Again, if there is an access to a page table entry in this state, it triggers a PAGE FAULT that causes the operating system to create a mapping to a valid page frame.)

During run time, an application can call system services to make logical pages valid in the logical address space.

As a safety check to catch stray pointers, most systems (usually directed by the linker) do not map the first page at all (however, the application can usually map the page through system calls). Your:

```
 int *a = 1 ;
```

Sets the address of "a" to a location that will be in the first page, which is always invalid.

Your

*a = 5 ;

causes the processor (memory translation unit) to access the page table entry for the first page. There, the processor finds that this page table entry is marked as invalid (i.e., having no possible mapping). That causes the access violation.

Comment: Isn't logical address synonym for virtual address? Otherwise a good answer. Could be even better if you mentioned how this ties with swapping pages to disk when physical memory is low.

Comment: No, virtual and logical are two related, but different concepts.

Answer (score 1):

The entire address space is not mapped to physical memory, only parts of it. You can't use addresses that are not mapped.

Usually some part of the address space is reserved for the operating system. Parts of the address space may be mapped to files, others to hardware devices. The whole idea of having a "virtual" memory system is that you can use a single address space to refer to multiple things, which also means that not all virtual addresses are "valid" all the time.

Comment: what parts of it? do you have a link for more info?

Comment: Finding the address mappings is OS-specific. The Linux kernel for example exposes this info in `/proc/self/maps`.